# Creating legend-style axis/scale in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Solution:**

I spent a little time looking into this, and came up with a decent solution. Lars is right, d3.js doesn't really allow for what I wanted, but with a little layering, it worked out. Basically, I created a new SVG to contain only the axis, overlaid it on the actual graph and tied the two zoom scales together. Here is the code:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .nice()
    .domain([-1, 1])
    .range([0, w]);

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .nice()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([0, 230]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .ticks(3)
    .tickSize(7);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .nice()
    .domain([1, -1])
    .range([h, 0]);
/* Control panning and zooming */
var zoom = function() {
    if( d3.event ) {
        zm.scale(d3.event.scale).translate(d3.event.translate);
        za.scale(d3.event.scale);   // don't translate so the axis is fixed
    }

            /* Do other zoom/pan related translations for chart */

    // Update x-axis on pan and zoom
    vis2.select(".xaxis")
        .transition()
        .ease("sin-in-out")
        .call(xAxis);

    vis.selectAll("line.link")
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return x(parseFloat(d.source.x)); })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return y(parseFloat(d.source.y)); })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return x(parseFloat(d.target.x)); })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return y(parseFloat(d.target.y)); });
};

var zm = d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([-Infinity, Infinity]).on("zoom", zoom);
var za = d3.behavior.zoom().x(xScale).scaleExtent([-Infinity, Infinity]).on("zoom", zoom);

    force = d3.layout.force()
        .gravity(0)
        .charge(-5)
        .alpha(-20)
        .size([w, h]);

    nodes = force.nodes();
    links = force.links();

    vis = d3.select(CHART).append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .call(zm);

    vis.append("rect")
       .attr("class", "overlay")
       .attr("width", "100%")
       .attr("height", "100%");

    vis2 = vis.append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", 300)
        .attr("height", 30)
        .call(za);

    vis2.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "xaxis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(20,10)")
        .call(xAxis);

    vis2.append("rect")
       .attr("class", "overlay")
       .attr("width", "100%")
       .attr("height", "100%");

    force.on("tick", zoom);
```

The result (with some additional CSS, of course) looks something like this, where the scale adjusts automatically as the user zooms in and out:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNO8r.png

**Original Question:**

I have a chart in D3js that displays a scale along the X-axis and appropriately updates as I zoom in and out. However, rather than having the entire bottom of the chart be a scale, I'd like to display the scale as more of a legend, like a distance scale on a map (ex. http://2012books.lardbucket.org/books/essentials-of-geographic-information-systems/section_06/91302d9e3ef560ae47c25d02a32a629a.jpg). Is this possible?

Snippet of relevant code:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .nice()
            .domain([-1, 1])
            .range([0, w]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(x);

var zoom = function() {
    vis.selectAll("g.node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + x(parseFloat(d.x)) + "," + y(parseFloat(d.y)) + ")";
        });

    // Update x-axis on pan and zoom
    vis.select(".xaxis")
        .transition()
        .ease("sin-in-out")
        .call(xAxis);
};
```

Comment: The link to the image is a 403.

Comment: I updated it to a new link that should work.

Comment: You can't really do that with the axis component provided by D3, but you are of course free to roll your own.